# Accepting but not saving bank account numbers in a web form

Tags: security, pci-compliance, banking

I'm working with a with a payment processing company that provides an API. One endpoint of this API requires a bank account number.

I'm not a PCI compliance expert or web security expert, so I want to tread carefully in this area.

What do I need to do in order accept a bank account number in a web form securely?

Comment: If you are not handling *card* account numbers then PCI-DSS does not apply, but you can of course use the PCI documentation as a guide for handling the data.

Answer (score 0):

See if the payment processor works with a tokenizing company, like Spreedly (http://www.spreedly.com). You can post your form for the bank info to spreedly, they return a token, which you then use with the spreedly api to post a charge etc. Other tokenizing companies do similar.